# how to copy only selected folders using robocopy?

Tags: command-line, robocopy

I have a directory in which there are 36 subfolders. I want to copy the last 18 folders using robocopy. How do I do that? Is there any option which I can use?

Answer (score 0):

This batch file should skip 18 folders and use robocopy with each individual folder after that.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=18 delims=" %%a in (' dir /a-d /b ') do (
robocopy "%%a" "target folder" switches
)
```